# Add character names and their lines to a new dictionary from array / list

Tags: python, regex, text, nltk, analysis

I have a movie script. My first job is to collect each character's lines in a dictionary.

Later I will need to put the data into a series.

Right now, I have all of the dialogue in a list, starting with the character names. It is formatted like this:

Dialogue[0]
'NAME1\n(16 whitespaces)YO, YO, good that you're here man.'

All of the names end with \n. And then all the lines of dialogue start with 16 whitespaces. I think this could be useful but im not sure how to make use of this.

I've tried a number of things but pretty much no luck.

```py
    result = {}
    for lines in dialogue:
        first_token = para.split()[0]
        if first_token.endswith('\n'): #this would be the name
            name, line = para.split(on the new line?)
            name = name.strip()
            if name not in result:
                result[name] = []
            result[name].append(line)
    return result
```

This code gives me a whole load of errors, so i dont think its useful to list them here.

Ideally I need each character as the first key in the dictionary and then all of their lines as the data.

Something like this:

Name1:[Line1, Line2, Line3...]
Name2:[Line1, Line2, Line3...]

EDIT:
Some of the character names have two words

EDIT 2:
Maybe it would be easier to go back to the original movie script text file.

It is formatted like this:

```
          NAME1
Yo, Yo, good that you're here
man.

          NAME2
     (Laughing)
I don't think that's good!  We were
at the club, smoking, laughing -- doing
stuff.
```

Comment: use this regex for splitting the data: `'([A-Z0-9]+)\\n[ ]{16}(.+)`

Comment: Before going to original movie script, please check my answer method 2 since it seems you have multilined dialogues. Since you know already know how to split between character dialogues, this might work.

Comment: In the orginal text file is the name always preceded by sevaral white space? and the dialog start from the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- split text lines
- create dict with unique keys for each actor
- add actors lines to dict

EDIT: added spaces in name regex, strip name whitespace

```
import re
lines = [
    "Dialogue[0] 'NAME1 \n                YO, YO, good that you're here man.'",
    "Dialogue[1] 'NAME 1\n                YO, YO, ",
    "Dialogue[2] 'NAME2\n                YO, YO, good that ",
    "Dialogue[3] 'NAME2\n                YO, YO, good that you're here'",
]

regex = h = re.compile("'([A-Z 0-9]+)\n[ ]{16}(.+)")
lineslist = [re.findall(regex, line) for line in lines]
lineslist = [ match[0] for match in lineslist if len(match)]
keys = [l[0].strip() for l in lineslist]
result = {k:[] for k in set(keys)}
[result[l[0].strip()].append(l[1]) for l in lineslist]
result
```

Output:

```
{'NAME 1': ['YO, YO, '],
 'NAME1': ["YO, YO, good that you're here man.'"],
 'NAME2': ['YO, YO, good that ', "YO, YO, good that you're here'"]}
```

Comment: Gives me an index error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: this has worked, however there's a small error where it's showing a character name with a space after as a different name

Comment: That's worked thanks! but there's another issue i've just noticed, there are 4 copies of each set of lines. As in, there's duplicates

Comment: @fishman what do you mean by set of lines, could you give an example?

Comment: as in, it finds all of the lines and thats fine. But then there's 4 lots of all those lines: https://ibb.co/Sdvj4hm

Comment: @fishman could you provide me smallest input sample that reproduces this error?

Comment: I reset all the variables and now everyhting is working again, no duplicates. Thank you very much. this was the code that worked.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED ANSWER: Going back to your original file, if we can assume all character names have 22 whitespace characters before them, we can do something like this:

```
example = """
                      NAME1
            Yo, Yo, good that you're here
            man.

                      NAME2
                 (Laughing)
            I don't think that's good!  We were
            at the club, smoking, laughing -- doing
            stuff.
"""

lines = example.split('\n')
characters = [line for line in lines if line.startswith(' ' * 22)]
result = {c.strip(): [] for c in characters}
current = ''
for line in lines:
    if line in characters:
        current = line.strip()
    elif current:
        result[current].append(line.strip())
```

The result is now:

```
{'NAME1': ["Yo, Yo, good that you're here", 'man.', ''], 'NAME2': ['(Laughing)', "I don't think that's good!  We were", 'at the club, smoking, laughing -- doing', 'stuff.', '']}
```

This might need some additional cleaning up

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am getting this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: can you try this? `name, line = item.split(maxsplit=1)`

Comment: Gives me the same error message: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: This isn't the same error... but anyway, then I'm guessing your data has inconsistent formatting that need to be cleaned up first @fishman

Comment: I've made an edit to show the original script. Could you explain to me how I'd get the same dictionary results from that? Maybe it would be easier that way

Comment: this code gives me all of the lines in the text seperately? I need the characters as one key in the dictionary and then their lines

Comment: @fishman I don't understand, that's exactly the result here, every character is one key and then a list of their lines is the value

Comment: @fishman exactly like you specified: "Name1:[Line1, Line2, Line3...] Name2:[Line1, Line2, Line3...]"

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Split by '\n' and strip. First element of the list will be name and remaining will be your lines. str.pop will modify your list in place.
This solution won't work if your dialogues have multilined lines.

```
>>> dialogue
'NAME1\n                abc adbaiuho saidainbw\n                sadi waiudi qoweoq asodhoqndoqndqwdq.\n                qiudwqd aisdiqnd asfiqwofnqofoweqomdomkmq!!'
>>> lines = list(map(str.strip, dialogue.split('\n')))
>>> lines
['NAME1', 'abc adbaiuho saidainbw', 'sadi waiudi qoweoq asodhoqndoqndqwdq.', 'qiudwqd aisdiqnd asfiqwofnqofoweqomdomkmq!!']
>>> name = lines.pop(0)
>>> name
'NAME1'
>>> lines
['abc adbaiuho saidainbw', 'sadi waiudi qoweoq asodhoqndoqndqwdq.', 'qiudwqd aisdiqnd asfiqwofnqofoweqomdomkmq!!']
```

**Method 2:**

When you have multilined dialogues i.e. dialogues might contain '\n' character, first split by first occurence of '\n' character. First element will be name and next element we further split by '16 whitespaces'.

```
>>> dialogue
'NAME1\n                abc adbaiuho saidainbw\n                sadi waiudi qoweoq asodhoqndoqndqwdq.\n                qiudwqd aisdiqnd asfiqwofnqofoweqomdomkmq!!'
>>> parse_temp = dialogue.split('\n',1)
>>> name = parse_temp[0]
>>> lines = parse_temp[1].split(" " * 16)[1:]
>>> name
'NAME1'
>>> lines
['abc adbaiuho saidainbw\n', 'sadi waiudi qoweoq asodhoqndoqndqwdq.\n', 'qiudwqd aisdiqnd asfiqwofnqofoweqomdomkmq!!']
```

As a function,

```
def parse(dialogue):
    parse_temp = dialogue.split('\n',1)
    name = parse_temp[0].strip()
    lines = list(map(str.strip, parse_temp[1].split(" " * 16)[1:]))
    return name, lines
```

**Note: Here for the 2nd split you can replace with whatever whitespace pattern you have. You can even split it with a regex. I have used simple 16 spaces here.**

**Code added on request for iteration:**

```
data = dict()
for _dialogue in dialogue:
   name, lines = parse(_dialogue)
   data[name] = data.get(name, list()) + lines
```

Comment: when running the function it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: can you paste a sample of dialogue you are using as input in the function in pastebin as input and put a link here.

Comment: Aah you misunderstood. I asked you to use it on the original question. i.e. dialogue[0] I assume is 1 dialogue of 1 character. I thought you already have that logic in place, is it not?

Comment: So I want you to use this on for every dialogue in the dialogue list that you have, as you mention in the original question.

Comment: How would I run the function on every single item of dialogue ?

Comment: just try on dialogue[0] as of now and tell if it works as expected. I will suggest after that.

Comment: ahh yes, that works perfectly. I get the character name and then their line as the value. So now i need the character name as the key and then all of their lines as the value

Comment: I added the code to iterate on entire dialogue list. dialogue_list is basically your dialogue list that your have. The code you ran worked well for dialogue_list[0]. See if this works.

Comment: the variable dialogue contains a list of all of my lines. if i change it to dialogue_list it gives me an empty dictionary: {}

Comment: ahh wait. When i run the function it gives me this: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'; I was using dialogue[0] and it was giving me just te first line of my lines, not a dictionary

Comment: you need to look the `data` variable in the snippet I added on your request, it is the dictionary you want, parse function just parses 1 single dialogue, it is just another utility.